# Debian package libmarkdown-php, how can I use it?

Tags: php

I am just wondering how do you implement libmarkdown-php in a php script?
By this, I mean:

- What code do I run to use the markdown library?
- Does it simply just add one function?
- Does it allows me to encode markdown2html and vise versa?

#### Where is a doc for this package, I can't find one? :(

Okay, so it terns out that I found the docs, just did not match them up, the project-page did not contain any info on it being the Squeeze package libmarkdown-php, Sad to know it is not in Lenny. Thanks @palhmbus for matching them. :)

Comment: This is far off topic, next time please [flag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/raising-a-red-flag/).

Comment: @JoshK This is not off topic, it is asking how to use a library that I wish to use in my software development. Please explain how this is exactly off topic. ??

Comment: @James: This is asking *How*, direct these questions to [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @JoshK : Then why close, why not migrate? BTW: For some reason I can't post questions on Stackoverflow, it says 'we are not accepting questions from this account' or something like that. I have 100+ rep so I don't understand.

Comment: @James: You have already accepted an answer.

Comment: @JoshK : Does that stop it from being migrated? If yes, I can un-accept it for you to migrate it, so I can then accept it on stackoverflow.

Comment: @James: No, it doesn't stop it. If you want me to migrate it now just flag it and I will do so.

Comment: @JamesM - it sounds like your posts have fallen foul of the "low quality" trigger. You need to contact team@stackoverflow.com if you can prove that your questions have improved. If that's the case I'm reluctant to migrate this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this in your php script

```
include_once "markdown.php";
$my_html = Markdown($my_text);
```

This is an example with PHP SmartyPants:

```
$my_html = SmartyPants(Markdown($my_text));
```

There is [plugins](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/) for wordpress & bBlog

Comment: so what you are saying is the only doc I found was correct, lol. :) In other words, I found this doc but did not think it was for the package, as it had a download markdown.php link, I did not think it was a package. :)

Comment: @JamesM-SiteGen - Putting Markdown on websites can help users, but remember to clearly tell them what the tags do. (http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/basics)

Comment: I know, I have read through daringfireball's whole project before, but it was not php, so I found libmarkdown-php and its source site with docs (did not know they matched up, until your answer).. Also I was disappointed to see that in /usr/share/php/markdown.php had all of its docs as comments, and was not in an external file, and also did not include the extras that are in the newer version, Though its not standard markdown, it should be libmarkdown-php-extra to allow both `require_once "markdown.php"` and `require_once "markdown-extra.php"`, agree?

Comment: Also said to find that it was not in lenny, Though soon enough my server will be fully migrated to squeeze. !!Debian RULES!!

Comment: once you have found markdown.php - make sure you include it with the right path, move it into onto your PHP path or /var/www/somewhere - And I agree !!DEBIAN DOES INDEED RULE!!

Comment: @palhmbus : My local computer has it installed and it is working perfectly, my Squeeze testing server has it, but my Lenny (web/mail/dns) server does not have it, so I simply added a modified version of the extended version. Copyright file includes docs. therefor no large file being included. :)

Comment: I went and removed dead code (for me), and got it down to 1000 lines :) I think I am going to rewrite the whole thing, too much code for little use :) Okay big use but still far to much code for what it is.